# Regex replace with accented characters - AutoHotKey

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I've encountered a problem using regex.replace with accented words - I'm using regex replace because I need to replace complete and not partial strings (see 'grund' in list).

But AHK seems to ignore accented characters at the beginning and end of words (in the middle it's fine). Has anyone come across this problem before?

I came up with the following "fix", by adding an underscore before leading accented characters after after trailing accented characters, but it still doesn't work correctly when an accent appears within a word (see 'mémit' and mèmit'). Could someone please help? I'm sure there's a much easier way to deal with accents!

Cheers!

```
^+f2::
data =
(
testé = WORD1
kragén = WORD2
und = WORD3
gürtel = WORD4
émail = WORD5
élder = WORD7
messé = WORD8
émit = WORD9
èmit = WORD10
testè = WORD11
)
text =
(
testé kragén und gürtel émail nomâtch élder messé émit émit èmiter émita mémit mèmit testé testè grund
)


text := RegExReplace(text,"(\w+é)\W|$","$1_ ")
text := RegExReplace(text,"\W(é\w+)"," _$1")
text := RegExReplace(text,"(\w+è)\W|$","$1_ ")
text := RegExReplace(text,"\W(è\w+)"," _$1")


loop, parse, data, `n, `r
{
stringsplit, term, a_loopfield, =, %a_space%
text := RegExReplace(text, "\b" . term1 . "\b", term2)
}


stringreplace, text, text,  _, , all
stringreplace, text, text, _ , , all


msgbox, % text
return
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to match the Unicode characters by using `\p{L}`:

```
([\p{L}\w]+)
```

**Example:**

**http://regex101.com/r/wD3wI1/1**

Comment: Thanks, but it's for a find and replace script, so I need an exact match of each individual word, not an all-encompassing regex code.

Comment: For an individual character such as the `é` you could likely use `\x(hex code of character)` - `([\xE9])`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work:

```
^+f2::
data =
(
testé = WORD1
kragén = WORD2
und = WORD3
gürtel = WORD4
émail = WORD5
élder = WORD7
messé = WORD8
émit = WORD9
èmit = WORD10
testè = WORD11
)

data := RegExReplace(data, "è", "00egrave")
data := RegExReplace(data, "é", "00eacute")
data := RegExReplace(data, "ü", "00uuml")

text =
(
testé kragén und gürtel émail nomâtch élder messé émit émit èmiter émita mémit mèmit testé testè grund
)

text := RegExReplace(text, "é", "00eacute")
text := RegExReplace(text, "ê", "00egrave")
text := RegExReplace(text, "ü", "00uuml")

loop, parse, data, `n, `r
{
stringsplit, term, a_loopfield, =, %a_space%
text := RegExReplace(text, "\b" . term1 . "\b", term2)
}

text := RegExReplace(text, "00egrave", "è")
text := RegExReplace(text, "00eacute", "é")
text := RegExReplace(text, "00uuml", "ü")

msgbox, % text
return
```